# launch vm on specific compute from horizon

Tags: openstack-horizon

Openstack CLI allows a selection of a specific compute with  `--host HOST or --hypervisor-hostname HYPERVISOR` or `--availability-zone ZONE:HOST:NODE` option during server creation.

Ref: https://docs.openstack.org/nova/train/admin/availability-zones.html

Is there an equivalent method available at Horizon? I see only a drop-down for the availability zone

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass the same hint through Horizon.

- You should go to the section `Scheduler hints`
- There type `availability-zone` in the left pane and click a + button
- This will create a hint with key `availability-zone` in the right pane
- You can then put `ZONE:HOST:NODE` value.